# Community Promotion Ads - 2015

Tags: discussion, community-ads

The dawn of a new year, 2015, now approaches, or has already approached, either way it means that it is now time to reset our Community Promotion Ads!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- community driven cooking blogs
- cool events or conferences
- helpful resources for both the new and the experienced cook
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2008).

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to properly advertise other sites so that we can for example promote the gardening site, which seems like a nice related topic some users might be interested in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Community Promotion Ads - 2016](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2152/community-promotion-ads-2016)

Answer (score 18):

[image: coffee.stackexchange.com]

Comment: While I was skeptical about advertising for a proposal, I think now that coffee in beta this is fine - we're sending people to a site where they can post, and it's where all the coffee fanatics are hanging out anyways, so I'm happy to see if we can help a related site get off the ground.

Comment: Image does not meet the requirements (too many pixels)... does that matter?

Comment: @derobert Apparently it works: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248622/what-size-should-community-ads-actually-be

Comment: I didn't even realize the proposal had gone forward... still don't understand why, given that almost all of those questions have always been on-topic here, and some have literally already been asked here.

Comment: @Aaronut Roughly I think the idea was that a stronger community might form that way, since a lot of coffee people have no interest in cooking, and more broadly a lot of people don't think of it as cooking. See for example http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/a/19300/23227 They did do the necessary area51 work. We'll see how it plays out. I do hope that if the beta doesn't go well, it won't be left for a thousand days like some - I don't think a ghost subtopic site is terribly helpful. But maybe it'll work out!

Comment: @Jefromi If you can edit, Rob would like it if you could change it to **COFFEE SE**, without the dot. http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/306/community-promotion-ads/307#comment1913_307

Comment: I also created a different version of this ad: http://i.stack.imgur.com/JMw2y.png Should I post it separately?

Comment: @Tim I didn't actually make this, so I asked the creator to edit, and I'll update it. As for other versions, you're free to post what you want, but I'm not sure we want two versions of the same ad, and it probably wouldn't get votes easily.

Comment: @Jefromi Yeah, I won't post. Maybe next year :)

Answer (score 11):

[image: gardening.stackexchange.com]

Comment: I just saw this on the main Cooking.SE site. It looks beautiful! The colors are lovely, the flower looks real and I like the lettering. It definitely makes me want to check out the Gardening site!

Answer (score 11):

[image: Visit Health Stack Exchange]

Comment: © [Tim](http://stackexchange.com/users/3203697/tim) 2015. Licensed [CC by SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)

Answer (score 6):

[image: Follow us on Twitter]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Comment: Do you happen to know why it has an incomplete border?

Answer (score 5):

[See all questions with active bounties http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/cooking.stackexchange.com/bounty.png](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured)

Comment: This is an adaption of [Community Promotion Ads - 2015](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/12383).

Comment: So, specifically, it will change to show the number of questions with bounties if there are any. I guess the idea is that the normal ways bounties are surfaced aren't enough.

Comment: Especially good with the new design, it really doesn't show off the bountied questions.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Comment: Community ads promoting other sites or proposals are only for sites that have some direct relation - is there some reason you think arts and crafts is related to cooking and would have an strongly overlapping user base?

Comment: Painting, modelling and sculpturing are widely used in cooking: see [this](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51%2BGGt9kzjL._SY300_.jpg), [this](https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRR30I_Al6NjbskyzTS6_vxD9Il-yJykcO7amYrWdtWnKTHW8a8bw) and [this](http://www.cakedesignideas.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Edible-Cherry-Blossom-Cake-Decorations-8.jpg)

Comment: I don't know about *widely* (most people don't make elaborate cakes) but okay, sure, we'll see how the voting goes.